# using awk to assign a value to a variable doesn't work with cron

Tags: bash, awk

I'm having problems when running a script from cron. First I found difficulties accessing to SQLite; now it's AWK commands that are running me crazy.

The problematic line is this:

```
sens=`awk -F, '{ if($2 == '${num}' && $4 == '$tipogalis' && $9 == "0")print $1 }' /usr/xbow/xserve/galtel/relasens`
```

Don't want to bother you with the details; it's the main line of a while loop that has to read the value of a column inside a file. It works perfectly from the command line, but running as a cron job gives no value to the variable "sens".

I already checked out that all the variables inside the line are read OK (num, tipogalis, etc.), so I'm pretty sure the problem is related with the amount of "&&" or with the "print" function.

Just in case someone wants to suggest something about the enviroment vars, I already added the following lines at the beggining of the script:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG
```

But made no difference.

Any other suggestion, please? I know the problem must be really tiny. Devil is always in details...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have verified that the `num` and `tipogalis` variables hold the correct values when you run in cron.

I'm guessing you're missing quotes around the constants in the awk if statement.

```
sens=`awk -F, '{ if($2 == "'${num}'" && $4 == "'$tipogalis'" && $9 == "0")print $1 }' /usr/xbow/xserve/galtel/relasens`
```

I'd use the `-v` option to pass the value into awk instead of piecing together the quoting.

```
sens=$(awk -F, -v val2="$num" -v val4="$tipogalis" '$2 == val2 && $4 == val4 && $9 == "0" {print $1}' /usr/xbow/xserve/galtel/relasens)
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn, but none of both options made any change. Maybe there's something I have to do in a different way with an AWK statement whe calling it from cron?

Comment: @Rorro, there's nothing special about awk in cron. It's probably something you're not showing us. Since the environment of jobs spawned from cron is very minimal, are you sure it's not perhaps a difference in your PATH or some other environment variable your script relies on?

Answer (score 0):

In the end the correct way was this one:

sens=`awk -F, '{ if($2 == '${num}' && $4 == '$tipogalis' && $9 == '0')print $1 }' /usr/xbow/xserve/galtel/relasens`

but the problem was not the line. My call was made to a $9 that was never equal to '0' due to an internal problem.

I'm sorry. This post can be even completely erased to avoid confusing other users.